# Regarding the maximum eigen value

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

In a paper, the author removed the matrix $P$ and use  the maximum eigenvalue multiplied by identity matrix , so is the following true?

> $$x^T P x \le x^T \bar\lambda(P) I x$$
>   where $x\in\mathbb R^n$, $P \succ 0$ is positive definite, $\bar\lambda(P)$ is the largest eigenvalue of $P$ and $I$ is the identity matrix

If yes, can you give me a proof or a reference for that?

Comment: Is your matix $P$ symmetric?

Comment: Presumably this is using a definition of "positive definite" that requires the matrix to be hermitian (symmetric in the real case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  This follows from the characterization of positive semidefinite matrices as those for which all eigenvalues are nonnegative.  If $\lambda$ is the maximum eigenvalue of a real symmetric (or more generally hermitian) matrix $P$, then the eigenvalues of $\lambda I - P$ are the differences $\lambda - \mu$ for eigenvalues $\mu$ of $P$, and therefore are all nonnegative.  So
$\lambda I - P$ is positive semidefinite, which says $x^T (\lambda I - P) x \ge 0$.

Comment: This characterization can be proven with the spectral theorem. (A legitimate protest to this suggestion is that the spectral theorem is harder to prove than this result; I mention it basically because the spectral theorem is a "named" result that is easier to look up than this one.)